# How to get log scale between two number with a set number of steps c#

Tags: c#, logarithm

I'd like to be able to get a log scale between two numbers, for x number of steps between a max and min value in c#

E.g.

```
var steps = 10;
var minValue = 10;
var maxValue = 1000;
```

Which would return this array with the values to the nearest int

```
[{1,10}, {2, 17}, {3,28}, {4,46}, {5,77}, {6,129}, {7,215}, {8,359}, {9, 599}, {10, 1000}]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How do you determine this scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it exactly like you would do it for a linear scale, except that you take `Math.Log` of your min/max values to determine the step and later do a `Math.Exp` to undo this transformation:

```
var step = (Math.Log(maxValue) - Math.Log(minValue))/(steps - 1);
for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:F0}", i + 1, Math.Exp(Math.Log(minValue) + i * step));
}
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks so much for this, exactly what I am  looking for